# CSS: Adding a Delay to Submenu Dropdown on Hover (Bootstrap 3 / MegaNavbar 2.2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, megamenu

Now i am officially desperated. I bought a Script to use a MegaMenu on my Site.
The Script is MegaNavBar 2.2
http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/meganavbar-v-220-advanced-mega-menu-for-bootstrap-30/full_screen_preview/8516895?_ga=2.119686542.744579007.1495443523-2131821405.1495443282

I wanted the script to open the submenus on hover, so i configured it as described on the Demo-Page (see above).

This worked fine. But i wanted to add a delay, because its irritating users, if they move the mouse pointer from top to bottom, and everytime the menu is open immediately while hovering.

What i tried:

- Asking the support - No Answer
- Trying to add an animation and animation-delay
  The Animation is working, but the delay is not working, i assume because of the "display:block"
- Trying to add an transition
  The Transition is not working, because Transition is not working with "display:block".

Is there anybody out there, who can help me with this stuff?

Here is my Bootply:
https://www.bootply.com/A50M0Wk9NK

(The assumed css rule is in line 29 of pasted css-code)

Best Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use Visibility instead of Display,  and thus use transitions.
e.g.:

```
div > ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}
div:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay:2s;  //set delay here
}
```

Comment: Hi Shtut, while the element is hidden using display:none, i can not use the visibility-option. The display:none is better, because the element does not reserve space, so as the visibility-option does.

Comment: @MichaelAix That's why the opacity is also there.  you can see examples and read more about it here- http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337

Comment: Perhaps you could have a look .. if i try your approach, the space is there, even with opacity:0  Look: https://www.bootply.com/bFVzPzmxpW

Comment: @MichaelAix  I see what you mean-  try adding `position: absolute;` to the ul styling.  that should fix it :)

Comment: I simply removed the attribute display:none, added the attribute visibility:hidden and then added the rules you mentioned above. Thanks Shtut for your help. You're the best one ;-)